# For each date - is it between any of the provided date bounds?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

### Data:

`df`:

```
            ts_code
2018-01-01    A   
2018-02-07    A
2018-03-11    A
2022-07-08    A
```

`df_cal`:

```
start_date  end_date
2018-02-07  2018-03-12
2018-10-22  2018-11-16
2019-01-07  2019-03-08
2019-03-11  2019-04-22
2019-05-24  2019-07-02
2019-08-06  2019-09-09
2019-10-09  2019-11-05
2019-11-29  2020-01-14
2020-02-03  2020-02-21
2020-02-28  2020-03-05
2020-03-19  2020-04-28
2020-05-06  2020-07-13
2020-07-24  2020-08-31
2020-11-02  2021-01-13
2020-09-11  2020-10-13
2021-01-29  2021-02-18
2021-03-09  2021-04-30
2021-05-06  2021-07-22
2021-07-28  2021-09-14
2021-10-12  2021-12-13
2022-04-27  2022-06-30
```

### Expected result:

```
            ts_code col
2018-01-01    A      0
2018-02-07    A      1
2018-03-11    A      1
2022-07-08    A      0
```

### Goal:

I want to assign values to a new column `col`: to 1 if `df.index` is between any of `df_cal` date ranges, and to 0 otherwise.

**Reference:**

I refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198681/how-to-make-new-column-with-string-value-if-it-is-between-two-dates-pandas). But it just works for one condition and mine is lots of date ranges. And I don't want to use dataframe join method to achieve it because it will break index order.

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check with `numpy` broadcasting

```
df2['new'] = np.any((df1.end_date.values >=df2.index.values[:,None])&
                    (df1.start_date.values <= df2.index.values[:,None]),1).astype(int)
df2
Out[55]: 
           ts_code  col  new
2018-01-01       A    0    0
2018-02-07       A    1    1
2018-03-11       A    1    1
2022-07-08       A    0    0
```

Comment: It works, but why using  df2.index.values[:None] not   df2.index.values.

Comment: @Jack, to reshape for broadcasting - to use `np.any(..., axis=1)` later. `ar[:, None]` is equivalent to `ar.reshape(-1, 1)`. `None` is an alias for `np.newaxis`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37867354/14627505

Comment: This is a Cartesian join. Since it is in C, it will be fast, albeit at the cost of memory. A more efficient method could be intervalindex or some form of binary search. But if your data is not that large, I think the broadcasting is sufficient

Comment: @sammywemmy my data is millions rows, another method is welcomed.

Comment: How many rows is df? How many rows is df_cal? For df_cal are there overlapping dates?

Comment: df_cal is original and there are no overlapping dates and there are millions rows for df.